# Escape slashes when using paste0

Tags: r

I'm trying to concatenate a few strings together, including a backslash.  However, I can't seem to escape the backslash correctly.

```
paste0("A", "\", "B")
```

gives me `Error: unexpected symbol in "paste0("A", "\", "B"`, while

```
paste0("A", "\\", "B")
```

returns `"A\\B"`.  What do I need to do to get `"A\B"`?

Comment: Run your results through `cat()` and you should see that `paste0("A", "\\", "B")` is actually working, and will have the right content if written to a file etc. When you `print` a character vector, R shows "\\" for backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste0("A", "\\", "B")` is correct. The string object will hold `"A\\B"` but if you [`cat`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/cat) it, it shows your expected output

```
>>> print(paste0("A", "\\", "B"))
"A\\B"
>>> cat(paste0("A", "\\", "B"))
A\B
```

Comment: But what if you're trying to use that pattern in say a regex? You can't use `cat` for that.

Comment: I had to do something like this once. I used `gsub` first to add escape characters and then `paste` to create my final regex and then feed it into `grepl`.