# Add quatation marks to every row of specific column

Tags: r

Having a dataframe in this format:

```
data.frame(id = c(4,2), text = c("my text here", "another text here"))
```

How is it possible to add triple quatation marks at the start and end of every value/row in text column.
Expected printed output:

> ```
> id text
> 4 """my text here"""
> 2 """another text here"""
> ```

Comment: You mean something like `paste0("'''", df$text, "'''")`?

Comment: @Sotos thank but they are not single but double quotes

Comment: Ok, then `paste0('"""', dd$text, '"""')`? But in this case you will see the escape slashes (which are not really there) when printing it

Comment: And you can run cat(paste0('"""', dd$text, '"""')) to see the expected output. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849205/escape-slashes-when-using-paste0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no `paste` nor `cat`/`paste` you can simply run:

`data.frame(id = c(4,2), text = c('"""my text here"""', '"""another text here"""'))`

```
  id                    text
1  4      """my text here"""
2  2 """another text here"""
```