# Paste does not return necessary output in R

Tags: r

I have a vector `a<-c("cars","balls")`, then I want to achieve following output `\"cars\",\"balls\"` using `paste0("\"",a,"\"", collapse = ",")`. However as an output I have only `"'cars'", "'balls'"`. How I can  I achieve the necessary output?

Comment: Try: `paste0("\\'",a,"\\'", collapse = ",")`

Comment: See also: [Escape slashes when using paste0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49849205/10488504)

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the question. You say you want `\"cars\",...` (word surrounded by double-quotes) but your `paste` command is concatenating single-quotes. Which is it? (The double-backslash is probably the key either way, but your question seems inconsistent.)

Comment: I updated the question. double quotes should be. And `paste0("\\'",a,"\\'", collapse = ",")` gives two slashes, but I need only one

Answer (score 0):

You need   `cat(paste0('\\"',a,'\\"', collapse = ","))`

Comment: Yes, it is working, but is it possible to do it without `cat()`, because I also need to save this `paste()` command as a df/vector?

Comment: Then `paste0('\\"',a,'\\"', collapse = ",")`is what you need

Comment: this gives three slashes `"\\\"cars\\\",\\\"balls\\\""`

Comment: I don't know how you want to store this in a data.frame/vector but it will be is the correct format you want

Comment: I need kind of this code `mydf<-paste0("\'",a,"\'", collapse = ",")`